# Custom "Condition" (org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition) that requires a dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I've seen several "how to write a custom Condition" (org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-conditional

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/java/composing-configuration-classes.html

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditional-annotations#defining-custom-conditions

All of these have had "trivial" implementations, or using "globally" available items (like environment variables).

I have searched and tried to find a custom Condition that needs a constructor injected dependency.

I get there is kind of a catch-22 because the @Conditional is during the process of registering the items into the IoC context.

Here is a complete (but "silly") example of what I am trying to do:

```
public interface IFavoriteColorFinder() {
    String findFavoriteColor();
}
```

..

```
public class FirstConcreteIFavoriteColorFinder implements IFavoriteColorFinder {
    @Override
    public String findFavoriteColor() {
        return "green";
    }
}
```

..

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionContext;
import org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata;

public final class FavoriteColorsAreCoolCondition implements Condition {

    private final IFavoriteColorFinder colorFinder;

    public FavoriteColorsAreCoolCondition(IFavoriteColorFinder colorFinder) {

        if (null == colorFinder) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("IFavoriteColorFinder is null");
        }
        this.colorFinder = colorFinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(
            ConditionContext context,
            AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {

        String favoriteColorValue = this.colorFinder.findFavoriteColor();
        boolean returnValue = favoriteColorValue.equalsIgnoreCase("red");
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

..

and then using java config

I tried "just the Condition annotation" as seen below.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Conditional;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
public class CompositionRootJavaConfig {



    @Conditional(FavoriteColorsAreCoolCondition.class)
    @Bean
    public ArithmeticException addArithmeticExcepiton() {
        return new ArithmeticException("This exists to test if FavoriteColorsAreCoolCondition works or not");
    }

}
```

That failed with a

> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [mypackage.FavoriteColorsAreCoolCondition]: No default
> constructor found; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
> mypackage.FavoriteColorsAreCoolCondition.()

So I made sure those other items were available:

```
@Bean
public IFavoriteColorFinder getAnIFavoriteColorFinder() {
    return new FirstConcreteIFavoriteColorFinder();
}
```

and even (below) tried to put the custom conditon into the IoC as seen below:

```
@Bean
public FavoriteColorsAreCoolCondition getAnFavoriteColorsAreCoolCondition(IFavoriteColorFinder colrFinder) {
    return new FavoriteColorsAreCoolCondition(colrFinder);
}
```

But it keeps coming back to "need default constructor" .. (on the custom Condition, aka, FavoriteColorsAreCoolCondition)

Is there anyway to create an "interesting" (non trivial) custom Condition that needs dependencies to figure out its boolean result?

Comment: `public IFavoriteColorFinder getAnIFavoriteColorFinder()` - make that static, retrieve it's instance via `(ConditionContext context).getBeanFactory().getBean(IFavoriteColorFinder.class)`

Comment: In my real-world...I have multiple implementations of the interface IFavoriteColorFinder.      But I will experiment with your BeanFactory suggestion.  and report back.. thank you.

Comment: Ok.  Pulling the item out of the context.....at run time......seems to be working.  Please post your comment as an answer  (I may tweak it after I get my code solidified).....but will be able to accept.

Comment: If your actual `IFavoriteColorFinder`-class(es) are `@Component` then you can use the `ConditionContext` to find your  `IFavoriteColorFinder`-component(s). On the other hand if the actual `IFavoriteColorFinder` are created as `@Bean`(s) then you have to make sure they are created before the `addArithmeticExcepiton`-bean. Initializing the bean via a static method won't help you

Comment: @DirkDeyne oops, yes, static factory bean suggestion was completely wrong, registering singleton via `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` should work

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov `@Conditional` and `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` ? looking forward to your answer... But most likely (_In my real-world..._ )the `@Condional`-bean will live in a library I guess, then there will be no problem... correct granadaCoder?

Comment: @DirkDeyne IMO, the main problem is TC would like to delegate further checks to bean somehow instantiated by `spring` whilst `spring` is trying to instantiate context, that is actually chicken-egg problem. If we take a look at how something ~similar was implemented in `boot` we may find out that in order to interact with context in their `@Conditional` implementations they were need to implement extra parsing phase, which currently works not so straightforward as "expected": developers do believe it is OK to mix `@ConditionalOnXXXBean` and `@ComponentScan`, however that does not work.

Comment: so, there are only two valid options: 1. do not use spring infrastructure at all (and use either service loader or SpringFactoriesLoader or something else); 2. inject bean into bean factory before it is starting processing context (that is either `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` or `SpringApplicationBuilder#initializers`)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of `Condition` explicitly states that

> Conditions must follow the same restrictions as `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and take care to never interact with bean instances.

This is why it requires default no-args constructor to be available and this is why declaring `Condition` with `@Bean` won't help.

So you can use neither constructor-based injection, nor `@Autowired`. As Andrey mentioned the correct way to get bean in `matches()` method is to use `context`:

```java
@Override
public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
  YourBeanClass = context.getBeanFactory().getBean(YourBeanClass.class)
  //....
}
```

Comment: Awarding bounty for not just stating "rules of engagement", but providing documentation for rules of engagement.